# How to get property fileds in Jersey?

Tags: jersey-client

Currently I'm developing the application which gets the property fields in front end and 
server handles this request using jersey.

In jersey I need to use more number of path parameters. So I'm looking for the solution
which gets the property fileds in a single element itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try sending **JSON** or you can send your data by separating them with a **delimiter** like Comma(,) or Pipe(|)

Comment: Thanks for your response sumit

But I just want to know that if any other solutions which exactly gets each property fields in jersey

Comment: give me a sample of the data you want to send. i was also facing the same issue and i solved it by sending the string like. params=(prop1=val1,prop2=val2,......) and then on server i was doing a  split on string

Comment: Sample data contains the fields such as dc1serverip, dc1serverport, dc1path, dc1tablename and dc2serverip, dc2serverport, dc2path, dc2.tablename.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sumit. I tried with the sample code. It's working fine for me

Comment: Since you don't want to use Path parameters, you can try using Query Parameters. `@QueryParam("username") String username;`        but i would suggest **JSON**

Comment: Referred this part: It says                                      @GET
public String get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = ui.getQueryParameters();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParams = ui.getPathParameters();
} Is this a right way to get property values

Comment: <button id='btn' value="test" name="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({fname:'Sumit',lname:'Jain'}),
        dataType: 'json'
    });
})
</script>

Comment: yes that is also right way....using query parameters is good option plus you don't have to worry about how data is being sent, you can just directly use them